# Is it possible to generate new text matching a vector embedding with an LLM

Tags: embeddings, large-language-models

I'm interested in generating variations of text using an LLM - is it possible to take a text embedding, move it in different directions in vector space, and generate new text from the resulting vectors?

Comment: Let's say you have a function $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and you have  $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $x, y \in \mathcal{X}$ and $y = x + 1$.